# Setting text from input to Ajax $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a button which creates an input like a simple todo list which gives the default value of '**This is the text**.' Instead, I want to replace the default text with the value of `<input type="text" class="addnewinput">`

The input which is created is after the .button is pressed is: `$('<input type="text">').val()`.

```
   $(".button").click(function (e) {
        $.get("ajax.php",{'action':'new','text':'This is the text'},function(msg){
                $('<input type="text">').val();
        });     
        e.preventDefault();
       });
```

So basically I want the value of this: `<input type="text" class="addnewinput">` to be the value of this: `$('<input type="text">').val()` after the .button is pressed.

OR, it will be much better if I can give the value of .addnewinput from the beginning as such:

I tried this for test:

```
    var abcdefg = $('<input type="text">').val('text')
    $.get("ajax.php",{'action':'new','text': abcdefg() },function(msg){
        $(msg).hide().appendTo('.todoList').fadeIn();
    });     

    e.preventDefault();
}
});
```

but it doesn't work

Hope someone can help me. 
Thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `value` of any input box you just have to say

```
$("inputSelector").val();//The selector should be any valid selector e.g input.addnewinput in this case.
```

I think you are looking for something like this

```
$(".button").click(function (e) {

   $.get("ajax.php",{'action':'new','text': $("input.addnewinput").val() },function(msg){
        $(msg).hide().appendTo('.todoList').fadeIn();
    });     

    e.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Got confused abit so I missed it

Comment: Mark it as an answer whenever you can.

Comment: Yeah, it takes few minutes before you can do so

Answer (score 1):

add id to your input and do something like

```
   $('#yourInputId')
```

instead of

```
   $('<input ...>').
```

If you do not want/can, you can simple do

```
   $('input')
```

but it will take all inputs. You can also do

```
   $('input').first()
```

to take only first element.